# Class Library Event Aggregator instead of Logging

Tags: c#, logging, .net-core, class-library, eventaggregator

I'm writing a class library and I'm wondering how I can pass messages to the consumer application for logging purposes. For Exceptions I plan to create custom Exceptions and throw them. But what's about information logging? Like: "Connecting successful".
I had the idea to implement some sort of event aggregator in my library and allow the consumer app to subscribe to certain events. Then the consumer app can decide if the want to log information or not.

Is this good practice? I just think Logging shouldn't be part of the library's responsibility.
Or are there any other ways to pass logging information to the user?